# VS 2008 unstable after "Stop Debugging"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

This was on Windows Server 2003 X86, VSTS 9.0.30729.1 SP

I used "Attach to process" to debug the program, but recently when I "Stop Debugging" by "shift + f5", I was prompted with an error saying "VS has an internal error and will be unstable". After that all the debug related menu items were disabled e.g. "Start debugging" and "attach to process" etc., even when I forcibly closed the program the situation remained, leaving me the only option to restart the solution.

The only reason I can think of causing this is that I forcibly kill the process a lot, in order to able to rebuild it quickly, other than that I didn't do anything abnormal to VS.

another sympton: when I tried to close the VS normally, I was prompted with "source file [] does not belong to the project being debugged" for all the files I opened inside of IDE, but the file does belong to the project.

Thanks for any reply.

Comment: Can you provide any details about the app you are debugging? web app, wpf, winform, c++?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this with a corrupted Visual Studio User Solutions Options file. Steps to fix:

1. Close the solution if it is open
2. Backup your .suo Visual Studio solution user options file (rename it to .bak)
3. Reopen the solution.

A new .suo file should automatically created. The problem should have gone away.